# Is there a limitation in JSF 2.0 to access attributes of the complex Managed Bean?

Tags: attributes, jsf-2, javabeans

The scenario is the following: 
A managed bean uses as attributes another managed bean, like `customerBean.current.customerAgreement`. When I display the data on a pge the expression `#{customerBean.current.customerAgreement.agreementTitle}` is filled and shows the expected output.

However in an `inputText` the value is only changed on the screen, not in the value I get back in the managedBean. Is there a limitation on how deep such a structure can be constructed?

Comment: Are there other fields in the form? If so, are changes to them being persisted to your model?

Comment: It looks like you need to merge your accounts. Can you change the e-mail used on both to match? If so, I can merge them easily. Additionally, if you put "Please merge with user 816165" in the profile of your current account, I can do the same. This will allow you to add comments on answers provided to you, edit your question and accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is basically no limitation in how deep you can nest beans.

Your problem is caused by something else. Perhaps you are not preserving the same parent beans in the request of the form submit as it was during the request of the form display. Hard to tell without further detail about your code. All what I can suggest is to try making `CustomerBean` a view scoped bean.